# Deterministic hashing in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

I'm using hashing of strings for seeding random states in the following way:

```
context = "string"
seed = hash(context) % 4294967295 # This is necessary to keep the hash within allowed seed values
np.random.seed(seed)
```

This is unfortunately (for my usage) non-deterministic between runs in Python 3.3 and up. I do know that I could set the `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable to an integer value to regain the determinism, but I would probably prefer something that feels a bit less hacky, and won't entirely disregard the extra security added by random hashing. Suggestions?

Comment: What is the purpose though? Why not to write simply `seed = 42`, unless you *actually want* the seed to be different on different runs?

Comment: @Alexey presumably because they actually do want the seed to be different when the context is different, but the same when the context is the same. Here, even if the context is the same, the seed will still be different.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64344515/python-consistent-hash-replacement

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a purpose-built hash function. [`zlib.adler32()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.adler32) is an excellent choice; alternatively, check out the [`hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) module for more options.

Comment: Watch out! I found out the hard way, but adler32's purpose is not for hashing, but for error correction. It has a rather high collision probability. Quite a headache to debug.

Answer (score 7):

Forcing Python's built-in `hash` to be deterministic **is** intrinsically hacky.  If you want to avoid hackitude, use a different hashing function -- see e.g in Python-2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html,
and in Python-3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html

Comment: Isn't a hash supposed to be deterministic ?

Comment: hash() is only deterministic _throughout the same run_, you have no guarantee it will return the same hash in different runs. Hence it's bad for persistence on disk.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually [use a string as seed](https://bugs.python.org/issue27706) for [`random.Random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed):

```
>>> import random
>>> r = random.Random('string'); [r.randrange(10) for _ in range(20)]
[0, 6, 3, 6, 4, 4, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 5, 7, 5, 3, 0, 4, 8, 1]
>>> r = random.Random('string'); [r.randrange(10) for _ in range(20)]
[0, 6, 3, 6, 4, 4, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 5, 7, 5, 3, 0, 4, 8, 1]
>>> r = random.Random('string'); [r.randrange(10) for _ in range(20)]
[0, 6, 3, 6, 4, 4, 6, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 5, 7, 5, 3, 0, 4, 8, 1]
>>> r = random.Random('another_string'); [r.randrange(10) for _ in range(20)]
[8, 7, 1, 8, 3, 8, 6, 1, 6, 5, 5, 3, 3, 6, 6, 3, 8, 5, 8, 4]
>>> r = random.Random('another_string'); [r.randrange(10) for _ in range(20)]
[8, 7, 1, 8, 3, 8, 6, 1, 6, 5, 5, 3, 3, 6, 6, 3, 8, 5, 8, 4]
>>> r = random.Random('another_string'); [r.randrange(10) for _ in range(20)]
[8, 7, 1, 8, 3, 8, 6, 1, 6, 5, 5, 3, 3, 6, 6, 3, 8, 5, 8, 4]
```

It can be convenient, e.g. to use the basename of an input file as seed. For the same input file, the generated numbers will always be the same.

Answer (score 2):

We could use several of the hashlib hashing algorithms.
Here is an example with sha1:

```
import hashlib

context = "string"
sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
sha1.update(str.encode(context))
hash_as_hex = sha1.hexdigest()
# convert the hex back to int and restrict it to the relevant int range
seed = int(hash_as_hex, 16) % 4294967295
```